# PHPExcel não está exportando alguns dados

Tags: php

Dei um `var_dump` no `$row_data` e todos os dados estão vindo, mas o problema é quando eu vou gerar os dados pelo PHPExcel de forma dinâmica.

Em uma tabela os dados são gerados, sem nenhum problema aparente. Testei em uma outra tabela (a maioria das respostas está em inglês) e apenas uma linha é gerada e várias colunas estão sem dados também. Dei um `var_dump` em ambas (`$row_data`) e os dados estão todos ali!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbname WHERE ID<30";


$i = 0;
$rowID = 2;

while($i < count($row_data)) {
    $col= 0;
    foreach($row_data[$i] as $key=>$value) {

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rowID, utf8_encode($value));
        $col++;
        echo $value."<BR/>";
    }
    $i++;
    $rowID++;
}


ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-type: application/octetstream");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Pq o `while`?  so o foreach não resolve? `$key`está sendo usado para algo?

Comment: Como esta usando a comunicação com o mysql? Teu `while` está usando `count` no $row_data, esta variavel é do fetchAll ou do fetch_assoc?

Comment: estou usando $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); (dei um ``return`` nele)

Comment: `$rowID` foi definida antes do while?

Comment: sim foi definida, atualizei o tópico também.

Comment: testei novamente: em uma tabela os dados são gerados, sem nenhum problema aparente. testei em uma outra tabela (a maioria das respostas está inglês) e apenas uma linha é gerada e várias colunas estão sem dados também. dei um var_dump em ambas ($row_data) e os dados estão todos ali!

Comment: Quando vc aperta `f2` nessas celulas em branco aparece algo? pode ser a formatação dela. poderia colocar uns dois itens do array pra gente saber como ele está organizado?